# Apples new section 3.3.1

Tags: ios, boost

With Apple making changes to section 3.3.1 on the iPhone dev agreement can one stillness libraries like boost in their apps?

I want to use Boost in my iPad app...

Answer (score 1):

Boost C++ Libraries, are just that.. Libraries written in C++. Nothing in 3.3.1 prohibits their use. The one exception would be if you want to use the Boost Python Library. But that would not be strictly a violation of that section. But using Python might be. It's still an open question as to the ability of Apple to enforce the rule changes. And more to the point.. If they will retroactively enforce it since there are many iPhone applications written in Python.